# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' after installing module

Tags: python

I have installed matplotlib using  `'pip3 install matplotlib --user.'` However, I was still getting the same module not found error message. Searching in stackoverflow and elsewhere, I found out that '`sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib'` would do the trick. However, I got `"sudo is not recognized as an internal...."` so I dropped that. I now get, `"'apt-get' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."` Please help.

Comment: pip3 is for python3. Are you using the same version while executing the code? Like python3 test.py

Answer (score 1):

In pycharm, I went to File -> settings -> project interpreter -> '+' symbol at right-hand corner -> searched for 'matplotlib' -> installed it.

Answer (score 0):

please add some more details - what OS are you using? do you have administrative permissions on the machine?

some possible issues \ solutions

- you can try installing the library in the regular class library instead of the user home directory using the command `pip3 install matplotlib`
- you may have more then one python installation on the machine, and the pip command you are using may be part of a different installation then the python interpreter you are using

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have administration rights on that machine, you can use conda to locally install stuff.
Corey Schafer conda tutorial is very good
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJC6ldI3hWk

Answer (score 0):

First, do not try `sudo` and `apt-get`. Both are unix programs and you are obviously running Windows. Second, you should try: `pip install matplotlib`